# How to dynamic add new element in Angularjs

Tags: json, object, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` to loop my object value to view.
Then I want to have a button to add new blank element to the last of `ng-repeat` value.

How can I do this in angular?

My data is json object. I tried

```
In controller
$scope.objs = {'a': 'a', 'b':'b'};

In view
{{Object.keys(objs).length}};
But nothing show in view.
```

Update

```
<div ng-repeat="docstep in docs.docsteps" class="docstep">
   {{docstep.text}}
</div>
```

Then I want to get the length of objects so I can .length + 1 in the button click
But I have no idea how to get objects length. Or is there any better idea?

Comment: Is that all of your view code or is there more?

Comment: what does your ng-repeat look like?

Comment: Do you have an object `docs` that is an array of objects in a property `docsteps`?

Comment: No, they are object object not array @mitch

Comment: @vzhen can you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @sza fiddle added, please check answer's comment

Comment: where's the fiddle, remember to explain your question correctly and clearly!

Answer (score 1):

Bind a click handler to the button using **ng-click**:

```
<div ng-repeat="docstep in docs.docsteps" class="docstep">
   <input type="text" value="{{docstep.text}}">
</div>
<button ng-click="addNew()">Add another input</button>
When this button is clicked. It will add another blank input
<br>Which the new input will be docstep3
```

This is how your JS should look:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.run(function($rootScope){

    $rootScope.docs = {
        "docsteps" : {
            "docstep1" : {
               "text" : "a"
            },
            "docstep2" : {
               "text" : "b"
            }
        }

    }

    var c = 2; 
    $rootScope.addNew = function(){
        count++;
        $rootScope.docs.docsteps["docstep"+count] = {"text":count}
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** You should use **ng-app** to define work area for angular and use **controllers** to reside the models(**docs**) and define the behaviour of your view (**addNew**).

Comment: `docstep1,  docstep2` will be random in real data. I just hard code for testing purpose. By the way, is that possible to check the length in view?

Comment: @vzhen You need to loop over the object to know the length.

Comment: I　looped. But I have no idea how to get the length of objects. There is not array. I tried `{{Object.keys(docs).length}}`  but not working.

Comment: If lets say you have docstep1 and docstep2 in docsteps then what do you expect? length = 2? In the above code, c points to the length of the object you see. You don't need to loop over the object. Still if you wish to loop over it then you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array

Comment: the docstep1 and docstep2 are just testing data. In real life, i cannot know how many docsteps will be there. So I have to loop over it and know length. The example you gave is associate array.

Comment: Objects and Associative arrays are all same in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I took your `ng-repeat` and made it work. Notice I put your object in the `$rootScope` but you can apply the same object to any scope that your ng-repeat is in.

### JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.docs={docsteps:[{text:'A'},{text:'B'},{text:'C'}]};
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mac1175/Snn9p/

Comment: I modified your fiddle to my actual data and tell what I want. Please check it out.
http://jsfiddle.net/EvsGw/2/